# I get error when I want to extract tar file in the satrap folder

Tags: linux, command-line, tar

I am new in Linux , when I want to extract the tar file in the folder satrap I get this error :

```
You may not specify more than one `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label' option
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

I write this command in Linux :

```
tar  -xf  satrap.tar.gz -c /satrap_dir
```

please help me .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options are case sensitive. Your command as written is simultaneously trying to extract data (`-x`) and create it (`-c`). From context it looks like you actually want to change directory for the extraction (`-C`). The untested command therefore becomes,

```
tar -xf satrap.tar.gz -C /satrap_dir
```

Please note that generally you shouldn't be writing into a root level folder (`/satrap_dir`). That's what your own home directory is for.